# Is it valid to set a member variable of Singleton Class directly?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, architecture, singleton

I wonder the following code is valid, or not.

In main function, the 'testValue' of the member on 'testClass' will be set.
If printed by calling 'showTestValue()' method, the variable must be updated?
Or the variable may be not updated in some cases ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class testClass {
public:
    int testValue;
    static testClass* getInstance();

    void showTestValue();

private:
    testClass();
};

testClass*
testClass::getInstance()
{
    static testClass ins;
    return &ins;
}

testClass::testClass()
{
    testValue = 55;
}

void
testClass::showTestValue()
{
    printf("testVal is :%d\n", this->testValue);
}

int main(void)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        testClass::getInstance()->testValue = i;
        testClass::getInstance()->showTestValue();
    }
    exit(13);
}
```

Comment: Which part of the code are you concerned is invalid? What do you think is different about this code than how you would normally set or print class members?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Singleton can be defined as:

> Singleton is a creational design pattern that lets you ensure that a class has only one instance, while providing a global access point to this instance.
> [Refactoring Guru](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton)

It defines instantiation of the class, not the usage. So, technically it's ok to access and modify values.

That doesn't necessarily make it good practice, i.e. What if your instance is used in a multithreaded environment? How are you controlling atomicity of the value?

Once you've thought about those questions, consider an accessor method or operator instead of direct access, that way you can control how the value is set and react to the change.